# C# вывод всех свойств объекта

Tags: c#

Всем привет, нужна помощь, например, есть такой класс:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Value41 { get; set; }
}
```

При дальнейшем создании объекта, мне надо вывести все свойства объекта на экран консоли, я делаю это так:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Значение 1 = {obj1.Value1}");
...
Console.WriteLine($"Значение 41 = {obj1.Value41}");
```

Получается не очень красивый и громоздкий код, можно ли как то в цикле пройтись и вывести все свойства, может быть что-то типа такой конструкции:

```
foreach(string el in attrs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Comment: Это используется для десериализации json файла, на сколько я знаю, необходимо создавать именно такую структуру, либо использовать словарь, но к сожалению с тем json файлом использовать такой подход не очень, так как имеется множество вложенных структур.

Comment: Чем словарь вам не угодил (ну или массив, я не знаю какой JSON у вас)? У вас явно динамическое значение и искать его название ИМХО, бред.

Comment: JSON взят через API Google PageSpeed Insights: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed

Comment: И что вам там не нравиться?

Comment: Я как понимаю, там получится не очень красивая структура в плане Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>>. Но не везде она вложенная, из-за этого в возникает ошибка при парсинге

Comment: Вы если говорите про JSON, то наверно стоит его предоставить? Или вы хотите, что бы мы регистрировали все необходимые API для его просмотра? По виду из документации там простая структура классов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108254/discussion-between-vladlion-and-evgeniyz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать рефлексию: [метод GetProperties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperties)

```
foreach(var prop in typeof(Foo).GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj1));
}
```