# Найти объект в классе по имени объекта C#

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
public class Food
{
    public Item Apple;
    public Item Plum;
}
```

Можно ли как-то обратиться к определённому объекту этого класса по имени?

Допустим, в переменную передаётся слово `Apple` или слово `Plum` и в зависимости от того какое слово передаётся, мы получаем нужные нам данные из этого объекта.

В общем ищу что-то такое:

```
string ObjName = getObjectName();
Food food = getFood();
print(food." ObjName ".description);
```

Comment: Да используйте вы наконец уже JSON.NET! Вон у человека тоже [проблемы были](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127716/220553) со стандартным парсером, установил JSON.NET и сразу жизнь легче стала. Сейчас вы пытаетесь найти костыли, а не решение.

Comment: Да я уже всё решил с Json, теперь всё парсит и собирает.
Этот вопрос к прошлым не относится, в моём случае это будет действительно хорошим решением. Если это вообще возможно

Comment: Понимаете в чем дело... Такие подходы, которые вы просите обычно используют в крайних случаях, очень крайних, если вы пытаетесь подобное сделать, то скорей всего у вас неверная структура вашего приложения. Ну если прям так хочется, то совсем недавно был вопрос, где [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128510/220553) было решение необходимое вам.